# Google TV change pointer click sound programmatically

Tags: google-tv

I'm working on a game for Google TV (Sony NSZ-GS7) which uses the touchpad to move things around.
AFAIK it is not possible (yet) to change or disable the pointer Arrow-bitmap programmatically, which is pretty shitty from game design perspective, is it at least possible to disable the default click-sound played by the device on every click so i can replace it with my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to disable the standard onClick noise using setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);